# The Sensation of being unable to identify nigh-recognizable things?

Tags: single-word-requests

As explored in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0F7XBwFwA-M), and [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/interestingasfuck/comments/bhlnf1/this_pic_is_apparantly_from_a_simulation_of_a/) reddit post, this [image](https://i.redd.it/c6lwx6ijplu21.jpg) showcases an array of objects that, although bearing general recognizable features, individually cannot be identified inducing, in some instances, a vexing feeling in observers of said image. It has been described as resembling the Vision impairment symptomatic of a stroke.

What I believe to be a related example would be a word being on the "tip of one's tongue". One can recall a "signified" that could describe, or be appropriate to the context of an event, yet cannot recall it's corresponding "signifier". This example however differs in that it can be resolved by eventually recalling the word, whereas the objects showcased in the image, fundamentally cannot (*I believe the image was created via AI, blending elements of multiple images to create one anew, ultimately mixing disparate elements such that the end product is an non-identifiable mishmash*)

**Is there a term that describes the sensation of having a general familiarity of something, yet inability to recognize said thing's identity?**

Comment: I would call it "out of focus".

Comment: Related: [Is there a word to name being unable to think of “proper terminology” for something?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/162303/is-there-a-word-to-name-being-unable-to-think-of-proper-terminology-for-someth/162305#162305)

Comment: Well video and reddit link all points to a representation of an image which is seen by a person having a stroke. If you make a quick google search then you find that one of the symptom  of stroke is vision impairment. So, you can simply call it vision impairment.